# Getting one particular array in a group of array

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have arrays from my json response but i need to get one particular array base on the condition. I have made some testings however, i still get the whole array.

here is the code:

```
$scope.currentLocationDetails=[]; //this would be the new array

 .success(function(response){
                response.forEach(function(res){
                    if(res.loc_name === $scope.currentLoc){
                        $scope.currentLocDetails.push(res);
                    }
```

heres how should it work:

```
NameDetails[]= {a:[me, you, her], b:[his, mine, theirs]},{a:[we, us, they], b:[them, am, I]};

if b=='his'
newArray[]=[his, mine, theirs]
```

Comment: are you getting above json in `response` ? ie `{a:[me, you, her], b:[his, mine, theirs]} ...`

Comment: yes i do. it is from a json response

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having a array of objects from json response. You're doing some little mistakes. You can use like below.

```
$scope.currentLocationDetails = []; //this would be the new array
$scope.currentLoc = 'his'; // store what you want to traverse from response

 .success(function(response){
     angular.forEach(response, function(res, key){
         if(res.indexOf($scope.currentLoc) > -1){ //check your value exists in array or not 
               $scope.currentLocDetails.push(res);
         }
```

For further reading I'd suggest you to read how [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) works.

Comment: it keeps returning 'res.indexOf' is not a function